# C# Monogame - premultiplied alpha

Tags: c#, fadein, monogame

I need a fade effect for transition between my screens. I've read online that old method for alpha blending from XNA 3 is deprecated and XNA 4's premultiplied alpha should be used. So I'm using Monogame and I assume the code would be the same but can you explain more about this premultiplied alpha? Also a code example compatible with my own code would be great! Here's some of it:

```
// Variables
private Texture2D image;
private Vector2 imagePosition;
private Color startColour;
private Color endColour;
private float alpha;

// Constructor
public myClass()
{
    startColour = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    endColour = new Color(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f);
    alpha = 0.0f;
}

// Update method
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // ??????
}

// Draw method
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(image, imagePos, startColour * alpha); // ???
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

I believe most of the code is there but I still need to update the alpha, change it from 0 to 1, or is that how you fade from white? I want to fade from white to opaque. So how do you do this? What code should I have in my `Update()` method and how should I change my current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be quite simple, if I understand right that you're trying to go from white to nothing.

```
public myClass()
{
    ...
    alpha = 1.0f; // I'm almost sure that 1 means solid
}    

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (alpha > 0.0f) alpha -= 0.01f;
}
```

Take into account that `Update()` is called every frame, that means 60 times per second by default (in current monogame version), so you have to adjust the decimal position of the `0.01f` to make it as fast as you want.

Also you can just go with `Color.White * alpha` in `spriteBatch.draw`. And you need to call the drawing of everything that is to appear before (above) the drawing of the "curtain".

Comment: Rather than relying on having 60 frames per second you can use the GameTime parameter to calculate the delta.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely better. Though from what I understood, the update method _shouldn't_ lag - the draw one should, so this shouldn't pose a problem. Of course, you can disable the fixed fps or set your own, so.. Yeah. :)